# Theme scripts run before DOM is ready in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have the following code

```
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>

    <script src="assets/js/vendors.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.9.1/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/pages/doc.script.min.js"></script>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" autostart="false"></script>        
</body>
```

and inside the `main.bundle.js` I have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Layout1.init();
    Blazor.start();
});
```

I can debug and see that DOM is not ready when Layout1.init(); is called which results button event listeners to not be applied e.g `var $sidebarCompactToggle = $(".sidebar-compact-switch");`

Does anyone know how can I achieve running the script after DOM is ready?

Update #1

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Layout1.init()");
        }
    }
}
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'init()' in 'window.Layout1'.
      Error: Could not find 'init()' in 'window.Layout1'.
          at https://localhost:44357/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:9198
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: I think that should be `InvokeVoidAsync("Layout1.init");` -without parenthesis- the InvokeVoidAsync sintax is `InvokeVoidAsync("your-function",arg1,arg2,arg3...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the script by using JSInterop...Just define a JS function to contain code to initialize JS objects, and call it once from the OnAfterRender(Async) pair of methods. These methods can contain code that should be executed after components are being rendered. They also get a boolean parameter that indicates whether the current execution of the method is done for the first time.

Comment: I tried it but I am getting an error. Check Update #1 on my initial post

Answer (score 2):

Document ready will always happen before your ui updates, for example, when you navigate to a new page you don't actually navigate, blazor just updates the elements on the current page and updates the url.

You'll have to make changes of values of the HTML element's `class` attribute in c#.

Comment: toggling of styles?

Comment: Reworded. Is that any better?

Answer (score 0):

Blazor is a relatively new framework that brought a new proposal in terms of solutions. But it wasn't designed for fighting JavaScript for DOM manipulation. But we can still access the DOM via interoperability.

Having said that, this solution worked for me on a simple project:

```
// index.html
<script defer src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
...

// app.js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  // Blazor might need some extra time to get ready,
  // so we give it two more seconds
  setTimeout(() => {
    let hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash) {
      window.scrollIntoView(hash.substring(1));
    }
  }, 2000);
});
```

But, if you still need that `init` function, maybe you can "wait" with a `setInterval()` function something like this:

```
init: function () {
  let timeId = setInterval(() => {
    const ready = document.querySelector("main");
    if (ready) {
      clearInterval(timeId);
      document.querySelectorAll(".anchor").forEach((element) => {
        element.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
          const url = window.location.href.split("#")[0];
          window.location.assign(url + "#" + event.target.id);
        });
      });
    }
  }, 500);
}
```

Finally, you can call it from within some specific component like this (don't call it globally, avoid "globalization" whenever possible):

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
...
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("init");
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

It's not a perfect solution, but it does the trick.